LottieView video lagging for a couple seconds in app
I am using LottieView from 'lottie-react-native' to render a json video file in my app. The file is 35Mb.
The video is lagging for a second then plays. The issue is, before the video renders and starts playing an empty screen is shown which I do not want.
This is my React component:
const Guide = () => {

  const { checkOSVersion } = useGuide();
  const { setGuide, guide } = authStore();

  const navigation = useNavigation<MainStackParamList>();

  const [isAnimationFinished, setIsAnimationFinished] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!guide) {
      if (isAnimationFinished) {
        handleSkip();
      }
    }
  }, [isAnimationFinished]);

  const handleSkip = () => {
    setGuide();
    navigation.navigate('TabStack', { screen: 'Dashboard' });
  };

  const handleAnimationFinish = () => {
    setIsAnimationFinished(true);
  };

  return (
    <Box flex={1}>
      {checkOSVersion && (
        <LottieView
          autoPlay
          loop={false}
          resizeMode="cover"
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          onAnimationFinish={handleAnimationFinish}
          renderMode="AUTOMATIC"
          source={require('./guidevideo.mp4.lottie.json')}
          speed={1}
        />
      )}
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Guide;

I tried to "pre-load" the video like this:
  const [videoReady, setVideoReady] = useState(false);

  const handleSkip = () => {
    setGuide();
  };

  return (
    <Box flex={1}>
      <LottieView
        autoPlay
        loop={false}
        resizeMode="cover"
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          position: 'absolute',
          width: '100%',
          height: '100%',
          opacity: videoReady ? 1 : 0,
        }}
        onAnimationFinish={handleSkip}
        hardwareAccelerationAndroid={true}
        renderMode="HARDWARE"
        source={require('./combined.mp4.lottie.json')}
        speed={1}
        onAnimationLoaded={() => setVideoReady(true)}
      />
    </Box>
  );
};

and also tried setting hardwareAccelarationAndroid, and rendermode to hardware, but did not see a difference. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
